# How to deploy a React and an Express app on different providers when they both use tRPC?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, deployment, trpc

I have a React app and an Express app. I have configured both to use tRPC. In the client i have this file, that gets the AppRouter type from a relative path on my machine (this is the utils/trpc.ts file):

```
import { createTRPCReact } from '@trpc/react-query';
import type { AppRouter } from '../../../chatapp-server/src/api/root';

export const trpc = createTRPCReact<AppRouter>();
```

I want to deploy both these apps. I have successfully deployed my Express app on Render (a cloud provider), and my React app on Vercel, but of course, the React app didn't deploy successfully, and one of the problems is that I am looking for the AppRouter type relatively, and I don't have the serer code on Vercel. This is the errors I'm getting:

```
src/App.tsx(4,25): error TS2339: Property 'message' does not exist on type '"The property 'useContext' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend." | "The property 'Provider' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend." | "The property 'createClient' in your router collides with a built...'.
  Property 'message' does not exist on type '"The property 'useContext' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend."'.
src/main.tsx(14,8): error TS2339: Property 'createClient' does not exist on type '"The property 'useContext' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend." | "The property 'Provider' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend." | "The property 'createClient' in your router collides with a built...'.
  Property 'createClient' does not exist on type '"The property 'useContext' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend."'.
src/main.tsx(29,11): error TS2339: Property 'Provider' does not exist on type '"The property 'useContext' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend." | "The property 'Provider' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend." | "The property 'createClient' in your router collides with a built...'.
  Property 'Provider' does not exist on type '"The property 'useContext' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend."'.
src/main.tsx(33,12): error TS2339: Property 'Provider' does not exist on type '"The property 'useContext' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend." | "The property 'Provider' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend." | "The property 'createClient' in your router collides with a built...'.
  Property 'Provider' does not exist on type '"The property 'useContext' in your router collides with a built-in method, rename this router or procedure on your backend."'.
src/utils/trpc.ts(2,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../chatapp-server/src/api/root' or its corresponding type declarations.
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 2.
Error: Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "pnpm run build" exited with 1
```

Here is the rest of the files that are found in the errors:

App.tsx:

```
import { trpc } from "./utils/trpc"

function App() {
  const { data } = trpc.message.getAll.useQuery();
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <>
      <h1> asd </h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

main.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App'
import './index.css'

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { httpBatchLink } from '@trpc/client';
import { trpc } from './utils/trpc';
import superjson from 'superjson';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();
const trpcClient = 
  trpc.createClient({
    transformer: superjson,
    links: [
      httpBatchLink({
        url: import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL || '',
        async headers() {
          return {}
        },
      }),
    ],
  })

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <trpc.Provider client={trpcClient} queryClient={queryClient}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <App />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </trpc.Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

My question is as in the title: How to deploy a React and an Express app on different providers when they both use tRPC? And is this even possible? Is there something I can do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because my client needed node_modules to be installed on backend folder.
This wasn't an issue locally because I had node_modules installed on my /server/, and when I deployed the frontend I skipped running npm i on the backend. So to fix your issue, make sure when deploying your frontend to install node_modules on the backend.

I am using vercel to deploy my monorepo:
/client/ (tRPC create-react-app)
/server/ (tRPC express)

I've changed my root directory to be empty instead of /client.

These are my deployment commands:
[image]